# How do i find the average of profits grouped by weekday as opposed to average of profits within a weekday

Tags: sql, syntax, average, weekday

whats wrong with my code? if i remove the code after from and before the last group by it averages each and every sale within the weekday. But I want it to average of all weekdays.

```
select  [Weekday], Avg(Amountpaid)
from (select  Sum(Amountpaid), [Weekday], [Date]
      from 
           itsthegoodtable

      group by [Weekday], [Date]
     )

group by [Weekday]
```

It keeps bringing the error message

> incorrect syntax near the keyword group

Comment: Please add a tag for the actual database or DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Your query was missing an alias for the sub query.

```
select [Weekday], Avg(Amountpaid) 
from (select Sum(Amountpaid) as amountpaid, [Weekday], [Date] from itsthegoodtable
group by [Weekday], [Date] ) t
group by [Weekday]
```

Comment: what doesn't work? you need to be more specific about the error

Comment: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Amountpaid'.

Comment: try the modified one..it was missing a column alias `amountpaid` previously.

Comment: thanks all i was missing was that alias with and a name for my function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an alias to the value calculated with the sum:

```
select  [Weekday], Avg(Amountpaid) as Amountpaid
from (select  Sum(Amountpaid) as Amountpaid, [Weekday], [Date]
      from 
           itsthegoodtable

      group by [Weekday], [Date]
     ) ap

group by [Weekday]
```